# export table in xls file with ng-bindhtml

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel

when i use this function on the table follows.

```
var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
            type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
        });
        saveAs(blob, $scope.name+".xls");
```

Table

```
<div id="exportable">
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <td>Question</td>
    <td>Answer</td>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="q in ques">
    <td>{{q.Title}}</td>
    <td ng-bind-html="ans[$index+1]"></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

the excel file is like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTQxi.png)

an extra "â€‹" comes before every row from . how to remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this script

```
for(var i=0;i<ans.length;i++){
    ans[i] = ans[i]..replace(/\u200B/g,'');
}
```